# Powershell - Find Folder Permissions and Expand Groups Members

Tags: excel, powershell, permissions, ntfs

I currently have a script that grabs the permissions for a folder and all folders inside that etc(recursive), the script is below.

```
$OutFile = "C:\temp\Permissions.csv"
$Header = "Folder Path,IdentityReference,AccessControlType,IsInherited,InheritanceFlags,PropagationFlags"
Del $OutFile
Add-Content -Value $Header -Path $OutFile 

$RootPath = "\\Fileshare\Folder"

$Folders = dir $RootPath -recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}

foreach ($Folder in $Folders){
    $ACLs = get-acl $Folder.fullname | ForEach-Object { $_.Access  }
    Foreach ($ACL in $ACLs){
    $OutInfo = $Folder.Fullname + "," + $ACL.IdentityReference  + "," + $ACL.AccessControlType + "," + $ACL.IsInherited + "," + $ACL.InheritanceFlags + "," + $ACL.PropagationFlags
    Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $OutFile
    }}
```

This part of the script is fine. I would like to go on to get the script to grab the members of any of the groups listed on the folders permissions and then grab the members in the group, create another sheet in Excel per group listed. The sheet would be the name of the group and inside that sheet would be the members inside that group.

Would anyone have any pointers of how to go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

SG

Answer (score 1):

As general pointers:

1. To get member information on groups for a domain you will need to either utilize the Active Directory module, or query using ADSI adpater.
2. Then also consider you could hit a local OS group, could use something like `net localgroup '. [Examples here for PowerShell.](http://powershell.org/get-local-admin-group-members-in-a-new-old-way-3/)